# GDB reports "No line 92 in the current file." but I actually have line 92

Tags: c, debugging, operating-system, gdb, memory-size

I encountered a very bizarre bug when I test my interrupt module of my os class project which is based on HOCA system.

When I start my main function (which is from line66 to line101), but when I set the breakpoint at line92, gdb says

`No line 92 in the current file. Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?`

Do you guys know what's going on here?

Furthermore, when I set the breakpoint at line 92 and continue GDB, it reports :"

```
     trap: nonexistant memory
     address: -1
     memory size: 131072
     ERROR:  address greater than MEMORYSIZE


     Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
     0x0000002e in ?? ()
```

"

Source code is as follow:

```
/* This module coordinates the initialization of the nucleus and it starts the execution
 * of the first process, p1(). It also provides a scheduling function. The module contains
 * two functions: main() and init(). init() is static. It also contains a function that it
 * exports: schedule().
 */

#include "../../h/const.h"
#include "../../h/types.h"
#include "../../h/util.h"
#include "../../h/vpop.h"

#include "../../h/procq.e"
#include "../../h/asl.e"
#include "../../h/trap.h"
#include "../../h/int.h"

proc_link RQ;       /* pointer to the tail of the Ready Queue */
state_t st;         /* the starting state_t */
extern int p1();

/* This function determines how much physical memory there is in the system.
 * It then calls initProc(), initSemd(), trapinit() and intinit().
 */
void static init(){

    STST(&st);

    if(st.s_sp%PAGESIZE != 0){
        st.s_sp -= st.s_sp%PAGESIZE;
    }

    initProc();
    initSemd();

    trapinit();
    intinit();
}


/* If the RQ is not empty this function calls intschedule() and loads the state of
 * the process at the head of the RQ. If the RQ is empty it calls intdeadlock().
 */
void schedule(){
    proc_t *front;
    front = headQueue(RQ);

    if (checkPointer(front)) {
        intschedule();
        LDST(&(front->p_s));
    }
    else {
        intdeadlock();
    }
}


/* This function calls init(), sets up the processor state for p1(), adds p1() to the
 * RQ and calls schedule().
 */

void main(){
    proc_t *pp1;  // pointer to process table entry
    state_t pp1state;  //process state

    long curr_time;   // to store the time

    init();  // initialize the process table, semaphore...

    /*setup the processor state for p1(),  adds p1() to the ReadyQueue */
    RQ.next = (proc_t *) ENULL;
    RQ.index = 1;

    pp1 = allocProc();
    if(!checkPointer(pp1)){
        return;
    }

    pp1->parent = (proc_t *) ENULL; // ENULL is set to -1
    pp1->child = (proc_t *) ENULL;
    pp1->sibling_next = pp1;
    pp1->sibling_prev = pp1;

    pp1state.s_sp = st.s_sp - (PAGESIZE*2);
    pp1state.s_pc = (int)p1;
    pp1state.s_sr.ps_s = 1;  // here should be line 92

    STCK(&curr_time); //store the CPU time to curr_time

    pp1->p_s = pp1state;
    pp1->start_time = curr_time;

    insertProc(&RQ, pp1);

    schedule();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with full optimization on?

Answer (score 5):

Compile without optimizations. Use O0 gcc flag for that.